# Segmentation Fault because of Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have been having a ton of trouble because I have forgotten all of the rules of pointers.  I learned about pointers 3 years ago and haven't used them since.  I am receiving a segmentation fault in the line `contents -> setPrevious(&node)` in the function add in the  LinkedList.cpp file.  I believe it has something to do either with calling the setPrevious function or passing node as a pointer.  Any help would be great.  Thanks!

LinkedList.h

```
#ifndef LINEARNODE_H
#define LINEARNODE_H

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class LinearNode
{
    public:
        //Constructor for the LinearNode class that takes no arguments 
        LinearNode();
        //Constructor for the LinearNode class that takes the element as an argument
        LinearNode(int el);
        //returns the next node in the set.
        LinearNode* getNext();
        //returns the previous node in the set
        LinearNode* getPrevious();
        //sets the next element in the set
        void setNext(LinearNode* node);
        //sets the previous element in the set
        void setPrevious(LinearNode* node);
        //sets the element of the node
        void setElement(int el);
        //gets the element of the node
        int getElement();

    private: 
        LinearNode* next;
        LinearNode* previous;
        int element;        
};//ends the LinearNode class

#endif
```

LinkedList.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"LinearNode.h"
#include"LinkedList.h"

using namespace std;

//linkedlist constructor for an empty linked list
LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    count = 0;
    contents = NULL;
}//ends the constructor

//adds an element to the front of the linked list
void LinkedList::add(int element)
{

    int found = 0, current = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
    {
        if (contents -> getElement() == element)
            found = 1;
        else    
        {

            contents = contents -> getNext();
        }//ends the else statement
    }//ends the while loop

    if ((found == 0) && (count == 0))
    {
        LinearNode node;
        node.setElement(element);
        contents = &node;
        count++;
print();
    }//ends the if statement
    else
    {

        LinearNode node;
        node.setElement(element);
        node.setNext(contents);
        contents -> setPrevious(&node);
        contents = &node;
        count++;
//print();
cout << endl;
    }//ends the found == 0 if statment
}//ends the add function

//this function removes one element from the linked list.
int LinkedList::remove(int element)
{
    int found = 0, result = 0; 
    LinearNode* previous;
    LinearNode* current;

    if (count == 0)
        cout << "The list is empty" << endl;
    else 
    {
        if (contents -> getElement() == element)
        {
            result = contents -> getElement();
            contents = contents -> getNext();
        }//ends the contents.getElement() == element
        else 
        {
            previous = contents;
            current = contents -> getNext();
            for (int index = 0; ( (index < count) && (found == 0) ); index++)
                if (current -> getElement() == element)
                    found = 1;
                else
                {
                    previous = current;
                    current = current -> getNext();
                }//ends the else statement 

            if (found == 0)
                cout << "The element is not in the list" << endl;
            else
            {
                result = current -> getElement();
                previous -> setNext(current -> getNext());
            }//ends else statement  

        }//ends the else stamtement

        count--;
    }//ends the else statement of count == 0
    return result;
}//ends the remove function


void LinkedList::print()
{
    LinearNode* current;
    current = contents; 

    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
    {
        cout << current -> getElement() << endl;
        current = current -> getNext();
    }//ends the for loop
}//ends Print function
```

LinearNode.h

```
 #ifndef LINEARNODE_H
#define LINEARNODE_H

#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class LinearNode
{
    public:
        //Constructor for the LinearNode class that takes no arguments 
        LinearNode();
        //Constructor for the LinearNode class that takes the element as an argument
        LinearNode(int el);
        //returns the next node in the set.
        LinearNode* getNext();
        //returns the previous node in the set
        LinearNode* getPrevious();
        //sets the next element in the set
        void setNext(LinearNode* node);
        //sets the previous element in the set
        void setPrevious(LinearNode* node);
        //sets the element of the node
        void setElement(int el);
        //gets the element of the node
        int getElement();

    private: 
        LinearNode* next;
        LinearNode* previous;
        int element;        
};//ends the LinearNode class

#endif
```

LinearNode.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"LinearNode.h"

using namespace std;

//Constructor for LinearNode, sets next and element to initialized states
LinearNode::LinearNode()
{
    next = NULL;
    element = 0;
}//ends LinearNode default constructor

//Constructor for LinearNode takes an element as argument.
LinearNode::LinearNode(int el)
{
    next = NULL;
    previous = NULL;
    element = el;
}//ends LinearNode constructor

//returns the next element in the structure
LinearNode* LinearNode::getNext()
{
    return next;
}//ends getNext function

//returns previous element in structure
LinearNode* LinearNode::getPrevious()
{
    return previous;
}//ends getPrevious function

//sets the next variable for the node
void LinearNode::setNext(LinearNode* node)
{
    next = node;

}//ends the setNext function

//sets previous for the node
void LinearNode::setPrevious(LinearNode* node)
{
    previous = node;
}//ends the setPrevious function

//returns element of the node
int LinearNode::getElement()
{
    return element;
}//ends the getelement function

//sets the element of the node
void LinearNode::setElement(int el)
{
    element = el;
}//ends the setElement function
```

Comment: You copied Linearnode.h twice, and we can't see LinkedList.h here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    LinearNode node;
    node.setElement(element);
    contents = &node;
    count++;
```

This creates a LinearNode on stack, makes `contents` point to this node, leaves the scope at the following `}` - which invalidates `node` - and `contents` thereafter points to invalid data.

You need to rethink your whole class - a linked list requires heap storage, so you have to use `new` and `delete`

There's several other errors in your source, but you should fix this basic misconception first, and then come back with an updated question if needed.

Some of the other errors:

- Lack of copy constructors, assignment operators and destructors
- No check for null before dereferencing pointers
- Not setting all pointers to null in constructors

Comment: okay I fixed it so that Its LinearNode* node = new LinearNode but I am still getting a segmentation fault.  It occurs when previous = node in the LinearNode.cpp file

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not allocating Node in the heap, only on the stack.

In the **add** function

```
 LinearNode node;
 node.setElement(element);
 contents = &node;
 count++;
```

Should be:

```
 LinearNode* node = new LinearNode;
 node->setElement(element);
 contents = node;
 count++;
```

Comment: that is why I use python most of the time

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of code to go through looking for every little problem, but one bad thing that jumps out is in LinkedList::add(). There you're declaring "node" on the stack, and then setting a pointer to point to it. When add() returns, that pointed-to object becomes trash -- the destructor is called. That's the kind of thing that leads quickly to segfaults.